# Stochastic Differential Equation Explanation

Tags: integration, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion, stochastic-integrals, stochastic-differential-equations

My process is the SDE $dX_t=X_tdt + dB_t$, for $t>0$, and $X_0=1$, where $B_t$ is Brownian Motion.
I was told I should solve using $Y_t=X_te^{-t}$.

How does it become $dY_t=e^{-t}dX_t-X_te^{-t}dt=e^{-t}(X_tdt+dB_t)-X_te^{-t}dt=e^{-t}dB_t$   ?

Comment: You get the differential of Y by using the Ito formula. In particular you need the first and second partial derivatives of $f(t,x)=xe^{-t}$ with respect to $x$ and the first partial derivative with respect to $t$. The first derivative wrt $x$ gives the "direct" change in Y due to change in X (your first term); the second derivative wrt $x$ gives the "additional drift" which in this case is just zero; and the first derivative wrt $t$ gives any drift that is explicitly built into $f$ without any reference to $X$ (your last term).

Answer (score 0):

can you take a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ornstein%E2%80%93Uhlenbeck_process ? Your question is intimately related to the so-called "*Ornstein-Uhlenbeck process*"